# Getting incompatible types on the server but local for maven build

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I am trying to maven build my Spring and Hibernate based project. When I build it using Eclipse, I get BUILD SUCCESS. And when I pushed the code on the server, I am getting COMPILAITON ERROR. I have done exactly same thing as I did on my local eclipse based environment and still I am getting this error.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/myusername/WebAppWS/src/main/java/abc/efg/webapp/controller/MyController.java:[122,54] incompatible types: abc.efg.webapp.orm.MetaData cannot be converted to abc.efg.webapp.orm.MyTerm
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

How can I troubleshoot considering the fact that the same thing works in my local eclipse setup and not on the server?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use the same java version on the server and locally?

Comment: I am not sure about the Java version on the server. Let me check. Could that be an issue?

Comment: please share this line .if it is small share whole method of this line:
/home/myusername/WebAppWS/src/main/java/abc/efg/webapp/controller/MyController.java:[122,54]

Comment: Buddy, you have to paste the source error in your question, there should always be a stack trace or exception thrown in the maven console output above the text you pasted in your question. Without that we have no way to help you! - Duncan

Comment: Also try to right click on the pom file in eclipse project explorer and select Run -> Run As Maven -> and for goals input clean install to see if you can maven build it locally.

Comment: Thanks guys. It worked. The problem was that I was missing one interface method declaration on my server code. Basically I was copying and pasting my changes from my local eclipse to server and that created this problem of missing method declaration. I think this is not a good way to update the server code from  my local eclipse settings.